# Some websites never finish loading

Tags: browser, website, http

I've got a really weird issue with my new system, certain websites never finish loading. The issue happens in IE, Chrome, and Firefox but Chrome is able to load some websites Firefox isn't loading and vice versa. So far I've tried:

- Three browsers (Obviously)
- Cleaing Cookies and Cache
- 8.8.8.8 / 4.4.4.4 DNS Servers
- Disabling IPV6
- Private/Incognito mode
- Restarting router and PC
- Another PC, which works just fine

I haven't had this issue on my old PC. Some websites kinda finish loading, some websites load forever while being stuck on **Waiting for http://mywebsite.com/** and some just time out (In Chrome). I'm really lost as to what I should try to resolve this. So far, nothing helped.

Comment: A given website always is unable to load or sometimes cannot be loaded?

Comment: If you click the refresh button on the browser for a site that failed, does it then load, or maybe it loads after a couple of refreshes?

Comment: @Ramhound Some websites (eg spotify.com) are not avaiable in Firefox but in Chrome, some websites load really slow in Chrome and aren't avaiable in FF at all. Now that TTT mentions it, this seems to work in Chrome and IE but not FF, it might be FF specific.

Comment: Do you have the latest Java ? https://java.com/en/download/

Comment: When websites load slow for me, it seems to give up and doesn't apply CSS and such meaning I get a partially loaded page that looks like it is from the 90's.  I am not sure the mechanics of it, but are really able to download and upload at sufficient speeds?  Have you checked your actual bandwidth at all?

Comment: O yeah, should've added that. Tested yesterday, 70Mbps down.

Comment: I know you mentioned that another PC works fine on the same router, but are you able to bypass the router with the problem PC and connect directly to the internet? It would be nice to completely rule out the router if possible.

Comment: Nope, can't bypass it. It's cable internet. Also, no second router avaiable, sorry.

Comment: Just to reiterate: you have a cable modem/router in one unit. You have two PCs connected to two of the ports in the back of the router. If you open web browsers on both PCs, and navigate to the same web page at the same time from each PC, PC 1 always works. PC 2 sometimes works and sometimes times out. Is all that correct?

Comment: Okay, I had some weird stuff going on with Chrome at the time, Chrome worked after some tinkering and the issue was actually Firefox. I deleted all of Firefox' data in AppData and copied the content of my old profile to the newly created one. That fixed it.